# How to use Eclipse ICE Geometry Editor?

Tags: eclipse

I am attempting to use the geometry editor from the ICE however, I am getting the following error, I have only installed the ICE and have no plugins or extensions so it is quite possible I am missing something however, I do not know what and where I can get it.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.ice.client.widgets was unable to load class org.eclipse.ice.client.widgets.geometry.GeometryEditor.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:329)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:278)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:316)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4821)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:94)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:173)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:617)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:581)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:770)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1214)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3261)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3176)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3158)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3117)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:324)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.lambda$1(OpenWithMenu.java:211)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4418)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4236)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3824)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ice.client.widgets.geometry.GeometryEditor cannot be found by org.eclipse.ice.client.widgets_2.2.0.201702201939
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
... 89 more
```

Answer (score 1):

**According to [Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_ICE), the Prerequisites are.**

> ICE requires a Java Development Kit (JDK) with Java 1.8 or greater.
>   Sun's version of Java can be used on Linux, Windows, or Mac, and OpenJDK can also be used on Linux and Mac.
>   **The ICE development team prefers OpenJDK for Linux systems. Some tools in ICE also require the installation of third-party libraries. While it is not necessary to install these libraries to run ICE, the Reactors and Visualization perspectives will not work correctly without them.**
>
> For Mac OS X ICE developers also recommend installing the Homebrew package manager.

**VisIt (Optional)**

> To visualize 3D data, ICE requires the installation of VisIt (minimum version 2.8.2) on a local or remote machine.
>
> VisIt is available for download from the [Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory website](https://wci.llnl.gov/simulation/computer-codes/visit/executables), and doesn't require any additional configuration to use with ICE.

**3D Graphics**

> ICE also requires that your system has 3D rendering enabled to edit geometries and visualize 3D data, which is normally done by installing the 3D graphics drivers from the vendor of your graphics card. You should consult your IT specialist if you do not know how to enable this feature on your machine.
>
> Certain features in ICE, currently including the Geometry and Mesh editors, also require JavaFX. This is included in most versions of the JDK, but default distributions for some Linux operating systems (including Fedora and CentOS) do not. In that case, you will need to download the official nightly build from the [Java website](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

**Then in the terminal, run**

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /path/to/the/jdk installation/jre/bin/java 3
```

**or some number other than 3 if you already have multiple jdk installations. Then run**

```
alternatives --config java
```

And type in the number you assigned to the new JDK in the previous step.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my error despite having Javafx and Java 8 as well as installing VisIt however, this is an answer that draws from reputable sources so I will award you the bounty.